# Update ListView data from separate thread

Tags: android, multithreading, listview

I parse some xml content from site. When news item was parsed, i want to display him in list. When i parsed each item i called `onNewItemLoaded` method, which needs to be updated list view. I know that adapter needs to be updated in UI thread, so i launch this in `runOnUiThread`. But i still getting an error. What i'm doing wrong?

```
    private ListView listView;
    private NewsAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        final Parser parser = new Parser();
        adapter = new NewsAdapter(this,parser.getNews());
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        parser.setParserClient(new Parser.ParserClient() {
            @Override
            public void onNewItemLoaded(Item item) {
                // Update in UI Thread! What's wrong?!
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        adapter.updateList(parser.getNews());
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                parser.fetchXML("www.example.org"); // run separate thread
            }
        });
    }
```

Piece from LogCat :

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but 
    ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter 
    is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. 
    Make sure your adapter calls notifyDataSetChanged() when its content changes. 
    [in ListView(2130968576, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class   com.example.censor_client.NewsAdapter)]

            at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1555)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2087)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
```

Comment: What happens inside `getNews`? Just returning data?

Comment: Oh, problem resolved. Looks like listview doesn't appers on the screen when i try to update him.